# How to make a daemon which will accept arbitrary commands

Tags: java, linux, daemon

Right now the program can be launched in a linux terminal. Once running you can type various commands and the program will do stuff on the machine until the user quits.

I would like to make the program into a service that the user runs and it goes to the background. Then the user should be able to make commands to it. Like start and stop, and write something to a log and whatever else my program does. Note that I need to send it arbitrary commands that my program will handle, not just start and stop. Maybe this means it is no longer a daemon - I dont know. How do I do this?

Also, if this is not too hard, I would like to be able to run multiple instances of this service. But it is not essential.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It seems clear to me: @Jono wants to convert an existing command-line driven program to one that can run in the background and still read commands from somewhere.

Comment: I also dont know why this was closed. There are a bunch of good suggestions here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Since this was closed, I cant put in my answer for what I finally did. I narrowed it down to DBUS, Java RMI and Java Sockets. I decided to go with Java Sockets since it seemed to be the most lightweight and platform independent. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a more complex command channel for your daemon, such as D-Bus or JSON-RPC, then write a helper that converts arguments passed to it at the command line into D-Bus or JSON-RPC calls and then displays the returned objects/results.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). The user can write commands to the pipe and your daemon can read from it.

EDIT: If your program already reads from standard input then you won't even need to change it. See the gzip example in the linked Wikipedia article.

EDIT 2: To put it in the background you can do the usual `program &` in Bash. If you want it to put itself in the background then you can use the `daemon` function on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Telnet? ssh?

on client : `ssh user@server command`

Comment: ... How did you even come up with this?

Comment: He might have read `man 1 ssh` ...

Comment: @Stephen: And what does *that* have to do with writing a daemon in Java?

Comment: There was nothing about java when I posted my answer, and he can write a ssh/telent server/client in java.

Comment: @Ignacio - it is bad form to criticise someone for an honest attempt to answer a bad question, IMO.  At least 5 high rep people thought it was unanswerable ...

Answer (score 1):

Use xinetd.

Install xinetd, and place a service file in /etc/xinetd.d . (ubuntu/debian here)
For example:

```
service yourprogram
{
     disable = no
     socket_type = stream
     protocol = tcp
     wait = no
     user = root
     server = /usr/local/yourprogram/executable
}
```

Then, edit /etc/services and add:

```
    yourprogram  1339/tcp
```

If people connect to port 1339 they get a fresh instance of that program, defined at the server line..

But, be careful because it runs as root! Make sure you have a good firewall or a way to authenticate users, because you're giving everyone root access on your machine if your program has a bug.